# Exchange PowerShell: How to pass multiple value, by variable, to -Members (or -ManagedBy) parameter of New-DistributionGroup command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've done the following script in Exchange PowerShell to add more than 1 new distribution groups in exchenge by powershell and add multiple members in them, all at once:

```
# bulk_DistributionGroup1.ps1
# Connessione al server Exchange con remote PowerShell
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$userCredential = Get-Credential -credential com_spoleto\rossetti.admin
$session = New-PSSession `
     -ConfigurationName  Microsoft.Exchange `
     -ConnectionUri http://srvexch13.comune.spoleto.local/PowerShell/ `
     -Authentication Kerberos `
     -Credential $userCredential `
      -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking

# Importa il modulo active directory per usare comandi AD
Import-Module activedirectory

# Memorizzo i dati da bulk_DistributionGroup1.csv nella variabile $adDistGroup
$adDistGroup = Import-csv "E:\BATCH\Bulk_AD_MX\bulk_DistributionGroup1.csv"
# Memorizzo i dati da bulk_DistributionGroupmember1.csv nella variabile $adDistGroupMember
$adDistGroupMember = Import-csv "E:\BATCH\Bulk_AD_MX\bulk_DistributionGroupMember1.csv"

#Ciclo ogni riga che contiene i dettagli di un gruppo di distribuzione nel file CSV 
$members = ""
foreach ($adGroup in $adDistGroup)
{
    foreach ($member in $adDistGroupMember)
    {
        if ($adGroup.name -eq $member.groupName)
        {
            $members = $members + ", " + """" + $member.member + """"
        }
    }
    $members = $members.Substring(2)
    New-DistributionGroup `
        -Name $adGroup.name `
        -Alias $adGroup.alias `
        -CopyOwnerToMember `
        -ManagedBy $adGroup.managedBy `
        -MemberDepartRestriction closed `
        -MemberJoinRestriction closed `
        -Members ${members} `
        -ModerationEnabled $false `
        -OrganizationalUnit $adGroup.OU `
        -PrimarySmtpAddress $adGroup.primarySMTPAddress `
        -Type $adGroup.type
    $members = ""
}

# Rimuovo la sessione Exchange
Remove-PSSession $session
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

and two .csv files one for passing values to the script (view the attached screenshot), but my script doesn't work returning the following error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> E:\BATCH\Bulk_AD_MX\bulk_DistributionGroup1.ps1

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                                     
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Script     1.0        tmp_gwg10zng.lky                    {Add-ADPermission, Add-AvailabilityAddressSpace, Add-ContentFilterPhrase, Add-DatabaseAvailabilityGroupServer...}                                                                                                    
Impossibile trovare il destinatario ""name1.surname1", "name2.surname2"". Assicurarsi che non siano presenti errori di digitazione o specificare un oggetto diverso.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=SRVEXCH13,RequestId=50679cad-e892-476e-a08c-f4e38475b793,TimeStamp=12/08/2021 07:24:56] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 3CCBFD1E,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewDistributionGroup
    + PSComputerName        : srvexch13.xxxxxx.yyyyyyy.local
 
Impossibile trovare il destinatario ""name3.surname3", "name4.surname4"". Assicurarsi che non siano presenti errori di digitazione o specificare un oggetto diverso.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=SRVEXCH13,RequestId=2ddfac63-b7be-48b4-b076-083d54dc78af,TimeStamp=12/08/2021 07:24:56] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] EC351391,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewDistributionGroup
    + PSComputerName        : srvexch13.xxxxxx.yyyyyyy.local
```

I there is anyone can help me please?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: It does look like it's pretty specific with the error message. The ['documentation for `New-DistributionGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/exchange/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) also has an example in Example 2 on how to add multiple users. Also it should be possible to shorten your foreach for the members to something like `$members = ($adDistGroupMember | Where-Object groupName -eq $adGroup.name | Select member) -join ','`. It does look pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$members` to be an array of member names, instead of a single string:

```
# define array
$members = @()

foreach ($adGroup in $adDistGroup)
{
    foreach ($member in $adDistGroupMember)
    {
        if ($adGroup.name -eq $member.groupName)
        {
            # add matching member names to the array
            $members += $member.member
        }
    }
    
    New-DistributionGroup `
        -Name $adGroup.name `
        -Alias $adGroup.alias `
        -CopyOwnerToMember `
        -ManagedBy $adGroup.managedBy `
        -MemberDepartRestriction closed `
        -MemberJoinRestriction closed `
        -Members ${members} `
        -ModerationEnabled $false `
        -OrganizationalUnit $adGroup.OU `
        -PrimarySmtpAddress $adGroup.primarySMTPAddress `
        -Type $adGroup.type
    # Clear array by creating a new empty one
    $members = @()
}
```

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen's solution works perfectly, Thanks!!! I have only another little question: I can not find the option to pass to new-distributiongroup command or some other command to set the parameter "delivery management: only internal senders or internal and external senders" can you help me or there is anyone can halp me?

Comment: @AndreaRossetti I assume `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled` or one of the `-AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom*` parameters on `Set-DynamicDistributionGroup` would do

Comment: @AndreaRossetti `Set-DistributionGroup` has similar parameters, feel free to [consult the documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-distributiongroup) - it's more likely to lead you in the right direction than I am, I haven't worked with Exchange for 5+ years :)

Comment: Ok but in my case it is not a Dynamic Distribution Group it is a Distribution Group, anyway i've tried to apply the following parameter to New-DistributionGroup comamnd: `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled "$true"` but I get the following error: `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name`

Comment: The syntax you want for boolean parameters is `New-Distribution -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled:$true`

Comment: `New-DistributionGroup` with parameter `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnable:$true` doesn't work it returns the following error: `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled'...`